# Standalone 10240 Windows UWP download

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a bunch of machines preloaded with 10586.  Unfortunately TargetPlatform version is setup at 10240 on a ton of samples I had.  Aka max and min is 10240.

For ease of use I'd like to just download outside of vs the standalone 10240 tools for uwp and install them.  But I cannot find where to download them after digging around.

I don't want to do each machine in vs2015, as the network situation is pretty bad at the location.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom VS installer that works offline, you will need to run Visual Studio with the /layout option. That way, you can configure you installer to also include the 10240 SDK (in addition to the default SDK that is required by the latest version of the Visual Studio UWP Tools).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx